# SQL Compact Service Packs silent install parameters

Tags: service, sql-server-ce, installation, pack, silent

my application needs SQL Compact SP1 and SP2 installed (Entity Framework), but there is nothing on MSDN where I can determine silent install parameters for those two files (SSCERuntime-ENU-x86.msi for SP1 and SSCERuntime-ENU.exe for SP2). And on top of that, 64bit SP1 needs to be installed like this: install x86 file and then install x64 file on 64bit machine. Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I've figured that out myself - all you need is to take these install files, run CMD and run them with wrong parameter, for example: C:\SSCERuntime-ENU-x86.msi -myAwesomeFlag. Because of course given parameter will not be found, install process displays MessageBox with a list of all possible parameters and their options. This works for both servicepacks and .NET 4 installation package.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking .msi install parameters are normalised compared to .exe (which can be anything the developper choose). I recommend using this command with those parameters for silent install: **msiexec /i SSCERuntime_x86-ENU.msi /qn /norestart**

**q** is for quiet

**n** is for No UI

**norestart** ensure that the computer doesn't reboot right now, this is useful if you deploy software with tools like SCCM, Chocolatey, etc. Otherwise if the software needs a reboot it will reboot the computer and if a user is working on it he will not be really happy ;)